# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()'

Tags: android, exception, bitmap

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<ModelCategory> model;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CategoryAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<ModelCategory> model) {
    this.model = model;
    this.context = activity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return model.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_adapter, parent, false);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_grid_image);
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.get_category_title);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.textView.setText(model.get(position).getCategoryName());
    if(position<=3){
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(StringToBitMap(model.get(position).getCategoryImage()));
    }
    else {
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(model.get(position).getCategoryImage()));
    }
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView;
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

    BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    option.inSampleSize = 8;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, option);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(getImageOrientation(path));
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotatedBitmap, 150, 150, true);
    return resized;
}


private static int getImageOrientation(String imagePath) {
    int rotate = 0;
    try {
        File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rotate;
}


public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
    try {
        byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        return bitmap;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

I am getting `error` like below..

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
>               at com.adapter.CategoryAdapter.getBitmap(CategoryAdapter.java:92)
>               at com.adapter.CategoryAdapter.getView(CategoryAdapter.java:75)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2896)
>               at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1456)
>               at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:361)
>               at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:302)
>               at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:437)
>               at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1284)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2700)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16899)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16899)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16899)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
>               at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16899)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16899)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16899)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16899)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16899)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16899)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16899)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16899)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your bitmap creation seems to fail. Are you sure the `path` value is correct and pointing to an actual bitmap?

Comment: Check again the getBitmap method, you are getting there the null pointer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Error traces show that error occours on

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, option);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

As the documentation of the `public static Bitmap decodeFile(String pathName, Options opts)` method:

```
 return The decoded bitmap, or null if the image data could not be
 decoded, or, if opts is non-null, if opts requested only the
 size be returned (in opts.outWidth and opts.outHeight)
```

This method will return null, if the image data could not be decoded. Note logs like `E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: ...` to find out this method why failed. Maybe you provided a wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that I was calling 'decodeFile' in background thread which was returning null. Moving that code to main thread fixed the problem.