# Error in int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am trying to get the song album art and make it blur it works fine but for one of the song it is getting crashed the song dont contain any album art ,But the app is not getting crashed for other song without album art .
This is what i am tried

```
 Uri myUri = Uri.parse(Singleton.getInstance().getAlbum_art());
    try {

        InputStream image_stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(myUri);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_stream);
        Bitmap blurredBitmap = GaussianBlur.with(this).maxSixe(100).render(bitmap);
        if (blurredBitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Bitmap blurredBitmap = GaussianBlur.with(this).maxSixe(100)
                .render(R.drawable.music);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
    }
```

The follow code works fine for other songs without any album art.This is the error that i am getting.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: beatbox.neelay.another2, PID: 25757
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {beatbox.neelay.another2/beatbox.neelay.another2.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3110)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3141)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2488)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                  at com.vansuita.gaussianblur.GaussianBlur.scaleDown(GaussianBlur.java:76)
                  at com.vansuita.gaussianblur.GaussianBlur.render(GaussianBlur.java:45)
                  at beatbox.neelay.another2.Main2Activity.update(Main2Activity.java:173)
                  at beatbox.neelay.another2.Main2Activity.onResume(Main2Activity.java:160)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1259)
                  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6379)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3099)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3141) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2488) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

So I tried to follow these two [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343191/nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-int-android-graphics-bit) and tried this way also

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(objElement, options);
```

I am doing this in try /catch so even if the album art is not available it will go to the catch block and it is going also for rest of the songs.How to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the file for the Album Art exists or can be found, however it can't be read into an image, or something similar.

The solution is making sure that the image your passing to be blurred isn't null:

```
InputStream image_stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(myUri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_stream);
if (bitmap != null) {
    Bitmap blurredBitmap = GaussianBlur.with(this).maxSixe(100).render(bitmap);
    if (blurredBitmap != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
    }
} else {
    Bitmap blurredBitmap = GaussianBlur.with(this).maxSixe(100)
            .render(R.drawable.music);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
}
```